# pancakeswap anti Front-Run

Tags: web3js, defi, pancakeswap, frontrunning

Please tell me how I can protect myself from the frontrunning on the pancakeswap exchange.
I use python3 and web3.py but when i set max gas price it is not help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use lower slippage percentages, know you said it but up your gas price, and also you could be specifically targeted to frontrun, in that case switch your wallet address.